# Instalei o IONIC , porém não tenho idéia de como fazer funcionar o PHP

Tags: php, ionic

Recentemente instalei o IONIC para desenvolver para Mobile, montei uma aplicação em HTML e funcionou ok, agora quero utilizar o PHP. O que preciso fazer ?

Comment: Nem eu. Vou esperar ver se alguém responde. Obrigado por perguntar. De nada.

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito. Você quer aprender PHP primeiro? Se for, tem que estudar. Agora, sua pergunta não está formatada de maneira adequada para que possamos respondê-la

Comment: Seja mais claro @AndersonMurakami. O que realmente deseja fazer com o PHP? Qual funcionalidade? Feito isso, fica melhor pra galera te ajudar. :D

Comment: EU QUERO SABER O SEGUINTE: EU POSSO USAR O LARAVEL COM O IONIC ?

Comment: @TaoPaiPai, sim, Ionic roda no client, qdo Lavarel roda no - PHP - server. =]

Answer (score 1):

O PHP vc irá fazer um backend para responder ao IONIC. Sua app Ionic irá consumir esse backend (normalmente API REST) atraves de chamadas assincronas - AJAX.

O que vc tem que fazer é estudar como criar uma API REST com PHP.

Não sou programador PHP, mas aqui tem um documento interessante:
[REST API Tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)

Comment: Quem deu downvote, pode justificar?

Comment: Pra mim a resposta é boa e explica bem, ionic é no mobile e o php é uma linguagem voltada para a web que dá respostas HTTP, sendo assim o ionic pode trabalhar com qualquer resposta HTTP e pra concluir qualquer linguagem no back-end pode trabalhar com o ionic, já que estão em camadas totalmente diferente e a interação é totalmente via http +1